# Spring Cloud Sleuth Zipkin 3.1.1 Missing some properties

Tags: spring-boot, zipkin

I use Spring Cloud Sleuth Zipkin with its version 3.1.1.

I have a problem about defining some properties in application.properties file.

The last two lines are in issue. I got an unknown property warning. How can I fix it?

```
spring.zipkin.base-url=http://localhost:9411
spring.zipkin.sender.type=web
spring.sleuth.sampler.probability=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late, but someone might find this useful.

You need to remove **spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin** dependency and add the following two:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```